# How to get last recent value only

Tags: sql, firebird, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables master `table1` and detail `table2`

`Table1` structure

```
table1_id integer,
description varchar(50)
```

`Table2` structure

```
table2_id integer,
table1_id integer,
price numeric(7,2),
Price_date date
```

I need to write SQL or a view that link between these two tables but the problem I want from `table2` only to get a single value that is the most recent one of the `price` field using the `price_date` field to be linked with `table1`, in other words I dont want to get any duplicates from `Table2.table1_id` field. how I should write that SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want all the latest entries for each `table1_id` from the table, and not just the latest entry (which is a lot simpler).

If you want the latest per `table1_id`, you first need to select the newest record per id, and then query the rest of the record, so something like this:

```sql
WITH latestprice (
    SELECT table1_id, MAX(price_date) AS price_date
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY table1_id
)
SELECT t2.table2_id, t2.table1_id, t2.price, t2.price_date
FROM latestprice l
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.table1_ud = l.table1_id AND t2.price_date = l.price_date
```

If you also want information from `table1`, then you need to add an extra join. Note that the above query has one flaw: if there are multiple entries for `table1_id` with the same `price_date` it will produce multiple rows and duplicates per `table_id`. If you want to enforce that this can't happen, you need to add an unique constraint for `table1_id, price_date`.